# Breadth and depth first search on a graph with returning edges

Tags: graph, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

[image]

I do understand depth and breadth first search but this graph got me confused as there is nodes that points to preceding nodes in the graph.

So let's say for instant that `N` is a goal state, then using Depth first search we would have

`A   B   E  J   K   L   F   G  M N`

So we is it correct this way ? I don't repeat the `A` because it was visited before right.

And using breadth first search I would go level by level and so I would have

`A B  C D   E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N`

Is this correct ?

And if we change the Goal state to `P`

then DFS will give us  `A  B  E  J K L  F  G  M  N H  O  P`

and BFS will give us  `A B C D  E F  G  H  I J K  L  M  N  O  P`

I feel I got this right, I am just uncertain if I am right because of the returning edges in this graph. So I just want someone to confirm that I am on the right track here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds correct to me. When pointing to a node that's already in your result set, it should not be added into the result set a second time.